# Обработка исключений из дочернего потока в родительском под Android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, исключения

Как отловить (а лучше пробросить в родительский поток) исключение, которое возникает в дочернем потоке? Пытался решить вопрос так:

```
threads.add(new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Делаем что-то
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
));
```

Не работает!

Comment: проще использовать Callable вместо Runnable, и возвращать составной объект, одно поле возвращаемый результат, другое поле обобщенный тип конкретной ошибки, это даст управляемость коду, ничего падать не будет и при необходимости можно кинуть и ошибку, а можно ее как-то обыграть без всяких try-catch конструкций

Answer (score 3):

[`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) вам в помощь.

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread th, Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Необработанное исключение: " + ex);
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Делаем что-то
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
);

t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
t.start();
```

Comment: Не компилируется. Пишет "error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown".

Comment: @Streletz не могу сейчас проверить, в метро. Скорей всего, нужно дописать `throws Exception`.

Comment: Спасибо. После небольшой доработки (замена класса исключения) заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Доработал решение от Suvitruf. У меня получилось как-то так:

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread th, Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Необработанное исключение: " + ex);
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Делаем что-то
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }
    }
);

t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
t.start();
```

На просто `Exception` ругается и не компилируется. Подсказку нашёл [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491606/java-thread-run-method-cannot-throw-checked-exception).

Comment: Ну, в целом, можно было просто правку в мой ответ внести. Но так тоже пойдёт (:

Comment: Принято. В будущем буду знать.